# Detection of Parrot Zik 2 under OS X by using Bluetooth framework

Tags: macos, swift, bluetooth

Under OS X, is is possible to use the CoreBluetooth framework to detect the Parrot Zik 2? Or am I oblige to use the IOBluetooth framework?

Doing this

```
central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)

public func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager!, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral!, advertisementData: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, RSSI: NSNumber!) {
    println("got \(p)")
}
```

Is only able to detect my Apple TV, but not my Parrot Zik 2

```
got <CBPeripheral: [address] identifier = [UUID], Name = "Apple TV", state = disconnected>
```

In the case I should use IOBluetooth, that would the code looks like?